# Kubernetes on Azure setup

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I'm trying to setup the Kubernetes default cluster on Azure from an Ubuntu VM.

I'm using this command

> export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=azure; wget -q -O - https://get.k8s.io | bash

But the process stops with the message about jq in PATH

> Unpacking kubernetes release v1.2.4 Creating a kubernetes on azure...
>   ... Starting cluster using provider: azure ... 
>   calling verify-prereqs
>   Couldn't find jq in PATH

Is it necessary any other step before doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer.

JQ Json Processor was missing on the machine.
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

Installing it fixed the problem
sudo apt-get install jq

It wasn't in the Kubernets prereqs documentation.
I think would be nice to have the complete list of dependencies in the docs and in the documentation.

Thanks